# Adding value to JSON child array dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, algorithm, angularjs

I am trying to implement a filter as shown in the image. I am using Angular JS framework, JQuery.

The requirement is , I have check box filter like Application Name , Status etc. On selecting an application or status I need to create a JSON dynamically like below . The value in "filterValues" should be automatically added or removed based on the check box values.

Based on the json value I will query the database and fetch the results and display.

I am constructing check box like below:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div ng-repeat="status in keywords.kw_Status">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{status}}" ng-model="isChecked" ng-change="change('Status','txt_Status',status,isChecked)">{{status}}
    </label>
</div>
```

The coressponding controller code is as below

```
$scope.change=function(filterCategory, filterField, filterValue, filterAdd){
$scope.filters[filterCategory]={"filterField":filterField,"filterValues":[filterValue]};
console.log($scope.filters);
```

}

Any help is much appreciated!!

[image: I am trying to implement a filter as shown in the image]

```
{
"Region": {
    "filterField": "kw_Region",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
},
"ApplicationName": {
    "filterField": "kw_ApplicationName",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
},
"IssueType": {
    "filterField": "kw_IssueType",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
},
"Outage": {
    "filterField": "kw_Outage",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
},
"Priority": {
    "filterField": "kw_Priority",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Besides what you want, also share what you have tried so far...

Comment: You're going to need to use push() and slice() - [JavaScript Array reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

> The value in "filterValues" should be automatically added or removed based on the check box values.

Use JSON.stringify and a replacer callback to achieve this:

```
function replacer(match, offset, fullstring)
  {
  return replacer.str;
  }

replacer.str = "\u0022filterValues\u0022:[\u0022hi\u0022,\u0022bye\u0022]"; /* Use DOM node value */

var foo = JSON.stringify({
"Region": {
    "filterField": "kw_Region",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
},
"ApplicationName": {
    "filterField": "kw_ApplicationName",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
},
"IssueType": {
    "filterField": "kw_IssueType",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
},
"Outage": {
    "filterField": "kw_Outage",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
},
"Priority": {
    "filterField": "kw_Priority",
    "filterValues": [
        "aa",
        "bb"
    ]
}
}).replace(/"filterValues[^\]]+./g, replacer)
```